# Add 1 word after readlines()

Tags: python, list, readlines

I am still learning python and have a question about the function readlines() The following is a part of my script:

```py
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
text = "".join(f.readlines())
print(text)
```

demofile.txt contains:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

Now I want to add a single word to this so I get:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
Example
```

I thought of something easy way of doing it:

```py
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
text = "".join(f.readlines())."Example"
print(text)
```

But that doesn't work (*of course*) I googled and looked around here but didn't really have the good keywords to search for this issue. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.readlines()` returns `list` you can `append()` to it:

```
with open("demofile.txt") as txt:
    lines = txt.readlines()
    lines.append("Example")
    text = "".join(lines)
    print(text)
```

or you can unpack the file object `txt`, since its an iterator to a new `list` with the word you wanted to add:

```
with open("demofile.txt") as txt:
    text = "".join([*txt, "Example"])
    print(text)
```

Comment: Note: In the unpacking case, you don't need `.readlines()` at all; the file object is an iterator that can be unpacked, so `text = "".join([*txt, "Example"])` works just fine, and only requires one temporary `list`, not two.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `open` function in python opens a file in read mode by default. Thus, you do not need to specify the mode `r` when opening the file. Secondly, you should always close a file after you are done with it. A `with` statement in python handles this for you. Moreover, instead of using `.` to add `Example` onto the end of the string, you should use the concatenation operator in python to add a newline character, `\n`, and the string, `Example`.

```
with open("demofile.txt") as f:
    text = "".join(f.readlines()) + "\nExample"
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you. While dealing with files. It is always recommended to use `with open('filename','r') as f` instead of `f=open('filename','r')`. Using `ContextManager` during file open is the idea that this file will be open in any case whether everything is ok or any exception is raised. And you don't need to explicitly close the file i.e `f.close()`.

```
end_text='Example'
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    text=''.join(f.readlines())+'\n'+end_text
    print(text)
```